# Check if a string has at least one number in it using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to know what the easiest and shortest LINQ query is to return true if a string contains any number character in it.

Comment: @saul whats the deal with the bounty? The marked answer is credible.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
"abc3def".Any(c => char.IsDigit(c));
```

**Update**: as [@Cipher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24730/cipher) pointed out, it can actually be made even shorter:

```
"abc3def".Any(char.IsDigit);
```

Comment: I couldn't find All() and Any() methods although I am using 4.5 framework. Do u know why?

Comment: @cihata87 make sure that you have added `using System.Linq;` in the top of the code file.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
public static bool HasNumber(this string input) {
  return input.Where(x => Char.IsDigit(x)).Any();
}
```

Usage

```
string x = GetTheString();
if ( x.HasNumber() ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Or simply `input.Any(x => Char.IsDigit(x));`

Comment: @Mehrdad, yeah I constantly forget about that overload

Answer (score 10):

or possible using Regex:

```
string input = "123 find if this has a number";
bool containsNum = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\d");
if (containsNum)
{
 //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
bool test = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(test, @"\d");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string number = fn_txt.Text;   //textbox
        Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"\d");   //check  number 
        Match match2 = regex2.Match(number);
        if (match2.Success)    // if found number 
        {  **// do what you want here** 
            fn_warm.Visible = true;    // visible warm lable
            fn_warm.Text = "write your text here ";   /
        }
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question, as the question was interested in short queries, and there are already many that are much more concise than this.