# C# Regex string must have at least one number

Tags: c#

How can I combine these two so my string only matches if it has at least one large letter and at least one number in it

```
return Regex.IsMatch(string, 
                @"\A(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})\p{L}+\z"); 
//but this works only with Big and small Letter, i dont know how I include the numbers

"^[0-9]+$" //Numbers

@"\A(?=\P{Lu}*\p{Lu})(?=\P{Ll}*\p{Ll})\p{L}+\z") 
//Letters which must receive at least one large
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with a number of sample inputs and sample outputs that match those sample inputs.

Comment: Does it *have* to be a regex? Why not simply `stringValue.Any(Char.IsNumber);` or `stringValue.Any(Char.IsDigit);`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string has at least one number in it using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540620/check-if-a-string-has-at-least-one-number-in-it-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly adapted from another answer: `(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])([A-Z0-9]+)`

[Fiddle with this on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8rMb0o/1) or [check the related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7684859/147191)